# Can't identify static and kinetic friction regions

Tags: friction

EDIT:I would like to say thank you to those who have commented so far trying to help me. It is really appreciated!!

In a project, I am analysing the frictional behaviour of different specimen on a number of surfaces. I am trying to identify which specimen provides better grip (i.e. greater coefficient of static friction), however there is no peak in frictional force before the slip region which corresponds to static friction.

As such I am unable to determine the static friction coefficient and have uncertainty as to whether the slip region corresponds to dynamic friction or whether there is some other mechanism being exhibited, such as stick-slip friction.

The attached picture shows the trend which is seen in every repeat (5 total for each surface) across 11 different surfaces (wood, metal, plastic, fabric etc).

The regions correspond to:

1) Specimen pressed down into contact with surface

2) specimen begins to move laterally

3) steady slip (?) region

4) Specimen lifted from surface

As can be seen, the friction coefficient (frictional force/normal force) is constant throughout the testing pretty much.

Can anyone offer any ideas as to why the results are coming out like this and what is possibly going on?

Many thanks

[image]

Here is the results I was expecting which gives me two definite regions where I can determine static and dynamic friction:

[image]

Comment: Why would friction change with time? Rather, friction would change with the force that pushed the object over the surface. See the first picture in http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/frict2.html

Comment: `[...] whether the slip region corresponds to dynamic friction or whether there is some other mechanism being exhibited, such as stick-slip friction.`

The "stick-slip" phenomenon is not a new kind of friction but merely a mix of dynamic (kinetic) and static friction. In general $\mu_s>\mu_k$, which may cause a small "jump" when the static friction limit is passed.  This might lower the applied force momentarily - just enough for friction to fall below the static limit again. This repeats and is called "stick-slip"

Comment: The measurements taken (time, normal force, frictional force) allowed the graph I posted to be devised. Then, I was calculating the ratio between the two forces to get the frictional coefficient.

I was expecting a peak in frictional force at 2, corresponding the static friction where i could measure the ratio.

Then, I was going to measure the ratio in region 3 to determine the kinetic coefficient.

But i dont have a peak for static, which makes evaluation of static friction impossible(?)

Comment: How are you measuring friction? Static friction may occur over such small time period that you might not see it.

Comment: I am measuring friction using a force sensing rig. The specimen is lowered onto a sample which is stuck to a force plate (region 1). then, the specimen is moved laterally, which generates a frictional force in response.

I'm measuring at a sample rate of 1 kHz, so I was expecting to see static frictional regiion somewhere. It seems illogical that static friction peak lasts less than 1/1000 of a second.

Comment: In reference to Steeven's comment about stick-slip: I am considering it is a possibility that this is what is happening. I just find it odd that it is exhibited in every single trial, even on surfaces with such different properties. My fundamental discussion at the moment revolves around the possibility of stick-slip behaviour, as I have no idea otherwise how to interpret these results.

Comment: I don't understand what you require explanation of.  The friction coefficient is constant throughout most of the test - as expected.  You seem to be saying that relative motion starts at 2, so this is kinetic friction.  The friction mechanism is surely irrelevant, and possibly cannot be identified by this experiment.  Possibly you are asking why there was no static friction force before the surfaces were in relative motion at 2?  The explanation for this might be somewhere in the details of how and when your apparatus applies or measures forces.

Comment: Because parts are not rigid it is possible the movement gets initiated by a strain wave along the material. For steel this wave travels at 5000 m/s and so if you have a 1m long specimen the time to unstick is in the order of 1/5000-th of a second. So yes, it is entirely reasonable you are missing it.

Comment: I understand that the unstick time can be very short. But, assuming static friction is at least noticeably larger than kinetic, i would expected to have seen a build up to the maximum static friction as there is no indication whatsoever of two discrete friction mechanisms in my image. What I require explanation of is why I am unable to calculate a value for static friction and a value for dynamic friction. As far as I can tell, I can only determine one value for static friction which is in region 3. Static friction is characterised by a peak in frictional force which is absent from my results.

Comment: I wonder if there is any significance in the fact that the decrease in the normal force at 2 appears to be equal to the increase in the friction force.  Possibly your test rig has been set up to measure only kinetic friction, not static friction, nor both.  The graph itself does not give any indication where relative motion starts and stops, and even if there was any relative motion at all.

Comment: To set the part in motion at an infinitesimal time you are looking at a frictional impulse being applied. I doubt you can measure this.

Comment: Are you pulling or pushing on the specimens ??

Comment: Yeah sammy, I was only able to tell there was relative motion by observing the rig. The only measurements taken were a force plate recording the normal force and a force plate recording the tangential force. There was relative motion at the interface, but i cant work out whether this is kinetic friction or some other friction mechanism as I wasnt expecting the results to look as they do.

Comment: The specimen is mounted to the underside of a plate which lowers the specimen into contact with the surface, then pulls it along for a few seconds before lifting away from the surface.

Comment: What happens if you plot coefficient (= friction force / normal force) vs time?  Does this graph show the behaviour you anticipate?  Does it have a peak?

Comment: sammy: plotting this gives me a gradual increase in friction coefficient when frictional force begins to increase. This stabilises at the same point as region 3, indicating the 'steady' region. I was expecting a gradual increase beyond the stable coefficient, followed by a rapid fall down to the stable coefficient.

Comment: In that case all that I can suggest (and it is only a suggestion) is that the difference between static and kinetic friction is too small to be measured by your apparatus.  Just because they can be different does not guarantee that it will be different.  The difference may depend on the condition of the surfaces, esp presence of contamination like oil or grease or moisture.  The apparatus  increases lateral force in increments, so possibly the narrow transition is taking place between these increments.  If the actual graphs are as smooth as your sketch, perhaps the output is being averaged.

Comment: If possible, I recommend that you consult the technician who maintains the apparatus, who is probably familiar with its limitations and settings.

Answer (score 1):

In your graph you have only plotted kinetic friction as a function of time and by the formula

$$F_k=\mu_kN$$

it remains constant because it is independent on the force(horizontal) you apply, surface area, time etc. however if you also include static friction in your graph it would have looked more like this:

[image]

Source: http://deutsch.physics.ucsc.edu/6A/book/forces/node21.html

From graph we can see:

Kinetic friction - remains constant

Static friction - increases and is equal to the force applied to remain in equilibrium until applied force is smaller than:
$$F_s=\mu_sN$$

based on experimental observation it almost always turns out that static coefficient of friction is greater than kinetic coefficient of friction

$$\mu_s>\mu_k$$

Therefore the maximum force that we can apply on an object so that it can remain in equilibrium is greater than the force of kinetic friction which is constant, because of this we can observe that force of friction is decreasing when the object starts moving which is seen in the graph above colored in green.